# errors in a loop

Tags: erlang, erlang-driver

Given the following loop on each element of a list:

```
lists:foldl(fun(X) -> ... end,N,Y),
```

How to catch the errors and continue to loop on the elements ?

Same question if this code is in a gen_server and if process_flag(trap_exit, true) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you just can't use [try/catch](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76650) like this?

```
1> lists:foldl(
1>     fun (E, A) ->
1>         try E + A
1>         catch
1>             _:_ ->
1>                 A
1>         end
1>      end, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, a, 6]).
16
```

Or you can use a decorator function if you want to extract error handling, like this:

```
1> Sum = fun (E, A) -> E + A end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.113037538>
2> HandlerFactory = fun (F) ->              
2>     fun (E, A) ->
2>         try F(E, A)
2>         catch
2>             _:_ ->
2>                 A
2>         end
2>     end
2> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
3> lists:foldl(HandlerFactory(Sum), 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, a, 6]).
16
4> Mul = fun (E, A) -> E * A end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.113037538>
5> lists:foldl(HandlerFactory(Mul), 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, a, 6]).
144
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st suggestion by @hdima is the easiest and gives you full control about how to handle different errors/throw etc. For example you may want to allow to throw as a form of non-local exit from the foldl. Are you really certain you want to ignore errors?

HandlerFactory though has an overly complex OO feel about it and seems a bit off. :-) It also severely limits your options.

This code will work within a `gen_server` as its effect is purely local. Trapping exits will not affect this, or be affected by it, as exits are signals from other processes and these are not caught by `try`. Turning on `trap_exit` results in all exit signals from other processes being locally converted to messages which are accessed using `receive` as any other message.